# Proof of "infinite" series

Tags: number-theory

This question comes from an exercise in programming ( the code is NOT the question)
Meta code

1. pick a composite natural number $N_1$
2. pick a comisite natural number $N_2 , N_2> N_1$
3. compute difference $N_2-N_1 =:d$
4. compute highest prime factor of $N_1 =:P_1$
5. compute highest prime factor of $N_2 =:P_2$
6. compute difference $P_2-P_1 =: D$
7. if $d=D$ compute product of $P_1 \cdot P_2 =: NN$

that is the exercise and now the question how to prove $NN$ series is infinite

or prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers which might be returned by step 7

Comment: What do you mean with "NN series (or rather sequence) is infinite"? -- Do you mean to say: There exist infinitely many pairs $(p_1,p_2)$ of distinct primes such that there exist composites $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $p_i$ is the highest primes factor of $n_i$ and $n_2-n_1=p_2-p_1$?

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Are you asking something like "prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers which might be returned by step $7$"?    If so, can you list a few natural numbers which might be returned by step $7$?

Comment: @lulu So far, I know that $6$ is a possible value (from $n_1=8$; $n_2=9$).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  That's the only example I have found, as well.

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

Comment: up to interval 1,000,000 step 7 continues to return but the processing time increases

Comment: Don't have a proper idea of a proof. That task was meant as simple intro to artificial intelligence, here , pattern detection, which can be coded in low level progam language not even object orientation is required

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_1,p_2$ be *consecutive* primes. As they are coprime, there are integers $u,v$ such that $up_1+vp_2=1$. We can assume that $0>u>-p_2$, for if $u\ge 0$ or $u\le -p_2$, we can replace $(u,v)$ with $(u\mp p_2, v\pm p_1$), perhaps repeatedly. Then clearly $0<v<p_1$. So $-u$ and $v$ are positive integers divisible only by primes $<p_2$.
We also know that $p_2-p_1$ is divisible only by primes $<p_2$.
Therefore, if we let $n_1=-(p_2-p_1)up_1$ and $n_2=(p_2-p_1)vp_2$, then
$$ n_2-n_1 = (p_2-p_1)(vp_2+up_1)=p_2-p_1.$$
Therefore, $p_1p_2$ is a possible output of step 7.

---

**Example:** With $p_1=23$, we let $p_2=29$. We find $-5p_1+4p_2=1$, so $6=-30p_1+24p_2$, which leads to $n_1=690$, $n_2=696$ where $n_2-n_1=p_2-p_1=6$.

Comment: Is it important for the primes to be consecutive?